# How to write sentences including bulleted copyright symbol

Tags: html, css, ampersand, copyright-display

how to write this sentence in the same line with a bulleted copyright symbol

```
"copyright .© 2015.All rights reserved"?
```

using code like this

```
<p>Copyright <li>%copy;</li> 2015.All rights reserved</p>
```

I expect it to be shown like this in the web browser:-

```
copyright .© 2015.All rights reserved
```

not like this:-

```
copyright   
.©  
2015.All rights reserved
```

Comment: Please add more information on the code that you are currently using!

Comment: Why would you need a bullet in front? I have never seen that used anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<p>Copyright &bull;&copy; 2015.All rights reserved</p>
```

Where `&bull;` is the html entity code for a bullet, and `&copy;` is for the copyright symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need the bullet, but if you need it, use another unicode char https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2022 :

copyright • © 2015. All rights reserved

or using entities:

`copyright &bull; &copy; 2015. All rights reserved`

copyright • © 2015. All rights reserved

More bullets: https://www.alt-codes.net/bullet_alt_codes.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're asking but from what i understand you want to know how to add a bullet before the copyright symbol. Adding • between two  elements is one way to do that. I'm not adding it as code because SO interprets it as markdown lol. If I have understood your question wrong please correct me and edit your question too!
I think you have to remove the `<li>` element and put a `<span>` instead.

Comment: Beat you by ONE second

Comment: Please let me have this, I'll finally have some respectable reputation :(